# How to update single object in sql to linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

For example

```
a = datacontext.customers.FirstOrDefaul();
b = datacontext.customers.Skip(1).FirstOrDefaul();

a.name="name1";
b.Name="name2";
```

When i call datacontext.SubmitChanges(), Two object updated. I don't want this.

I need only Update `a` object. How do it?

**EDIT**

```
WPFWindow windowA=new WPFWINDOW()
windowA.DataContext=a;
windowA.Show();

WPFWindow windowB=new WPFWINDOW()
windowB.DataContext=b;
windowB.Show();
```

When clicking save button from window, corresponding object saving. 
When clicking cancel button, corresponding object not saved

Comment: Note: If you use `FirstOrDefault` you should remember to check for possible null before accessing members on the object. If you want to omit the null test because you know that the operation will/should succeed then you should use `First` instead of `FirstOrDefault`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use separate DataContext's.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to save changes to b, then why assign b.name = "name2". Use a temporary variable to store "name2". Later you can assign it to b.name if you want

Comment: not use temporary. User maybe save "b" object. maybe cancel "b" object.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the purpose of a DataContext is to encapsulate a set of changes to be submitted together.  If you want some changes to be separate, create another DataContext instance.  DataContexts, I believe, are intended to be lightweight and quick to create and release.  In the application I have created that uses LINQ to SQL heavily, I create a separate DataContext for every window.  Do NOT use a shared data context for your whole application.  It's not like a database connection.  That's why the database connection is a separate object.